# Redirecting user after clicking div and a button with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code to redirect a user after clicking on the div and the next button ,
but it dosen't work for me :(

Here's my code

```js
$("a.xxx").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("yyy").toggleClass("xxx");
});
$(".resellc").click(function() {
var rid = document.getElementsByTagName('yyy').id;
location.href = rid;
});
```

```html
<a id="3" class="xxx"><div style="color: black; padding: 10px; border-bottom: 0.1px solid;">Apple watch</div></a><a id="18" class="xxx"><div style="color: black; padding: 10px; border-bottom: 0.1px solid;">Apple Watch</div></a><a id="21" class="xxx"><div style="color: black; padding: 10px; border-bottom: 0.1px solid;">BMW Bike</div></a><a id="30" class="xxx"><div style="color: black; padding: 10px; border-bottom: 0.1px solid;">Women lingerie</div></a>
<button class="resellc">next</button>
```

Thanks

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('yyy').id` will always be `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$("a.xxx").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var rid = this.id;
    $(this).toggleClass("yyy").toggleClass("xxx");
    $(".resellc").off('click').one('click', function() {
        location.href = rid;
        console.log(rid);
    });
});
```

```js
$("a.xxx").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var rid = this.id;
    $(this).toggleClass("yyy").toggleClass("xxx");
    $(".resellc").off('click').one('click', function() {
        location.href = rid;
        console.log(rid);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="3" class="xxx"><div style="color: black; padding: 10px; border-bottom: 0.1px solid;">Apple watch</div></a><a id="18" class="xxx"><div style="color: black; padding: 10px; border-bottom: 0.1px solid;">Apple Watch</div></a><a id="21" class="xxx"><div style="color: black; padding: 10px; border-bottom: 0.1px solid;">BMW Bike</div></a><a id="30" class="xxx"><div style="color: black; padding: 10px; border-bottom: 0.1px solid;">Women lingerie</div></a>
<button class="resellc">next</button>
```